# Projecting a vector in a given plane using numpy

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

Using `numpy`, how can I do an orthogonal projection of, for example, the vector `np.array([0.3,0.5,0.2])` into the plane `3x+2y-2z=0` ?

EDIT:

I think one may simply use `numpy.linalg.lstsq` to find the orthogonal projection?

Answer (score 0):

Your hyperplane is defined by the set of `x` such that `<a,x>=0`, where a is a vector orthogonal to the plane. In your example,

`a = (3,2,-2).`

Then The projection of a point `p` is in the hyperplane is a point `p_proj` such that `p-p_proj` is orthogonal to the plane. This means that it is parallel to a, or in other words `p-p_proj=lambda*a`. So

`p_proj = p- lambda*a (1)`.
since `p_proj` is in the hyperplane, `<p_proj,a> = 0` so multiplying by a on the equality(1) gives
`lambda= <p,a>/<a,a>`.
Substituting  into (2), you get

`Projection(p) = p_proj = p-<p,a>/<a,a>a`

which can be done easily in numpy using `np.dot(v_1,v_2)` wherever we encounter `<v_1,v_2>`:

```
def projection(p,a):
    lambda_val = np.dot(p,a)/np.dot(a,a)
    return p - lambda_val * a
```

(Note that this is a Gram-Schmidt iteration).